# Update database of mobile hub using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-mobilehub

I am trying to update database of mobile hub by running a cron task on aws.
I referred to the [docs of the boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/mobile.html) under mobile subsection and I can't find any thing substantial that can help me with it.

I want to know whether there is any way to update the mobile hub based database using cron task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Mobile Hub's database feature is create an Amazon DynamoDB on your behalf. You could just using it as regular Amazon DynamoDB tables. You find the Amazon DynamoDB table name under AWS Mobile Hub > your project > resources > Amazon DynamoDB. 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

Hope this helps.